# Issue in web scraping through vba from web page in internet explorer

Tags: vba, web-scraping, web-crawler

I would like to create a crawler which scraps city names and their respective number of restaurants from the website, but I am getting errors and unable to understand the process of getting class names and tag names.Please help me with getting the relevant elements of HTML in order to fetch the required details.

```
Dim ieobj As InternetExplorer
Dim iedoc As Object
Dim tag As Object
Dim str As String

Public Sub scrape()

Set ieobj = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    With ieobj
    .navigate ("**********")
    .Visible = True
    strtimer = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    Do Until .readystate = 4
    If TimeValue(Now()) > TimeValue(strtimer) Then
    End If
Loop
End With

Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

Set iedoc = ieobj.document

Set div_result = iedoc.getElementsByClassName("")(0)
    Set header_links = div_result.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText
    Set header_links1 = div_result.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Hyperlink
    For Each h In header_links
        Set link = h.ChildNodes.Item(0)
        Cells(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 12) = h.href
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: what error message your are getting? please share the website URL you are trying to scrape

Comment: To help you further you either need to share the webpage, or copy the part of source code you want to scrap, so we can see the element structure, and also the TagNames of each element.

Comment: I can't post it on comments section, It would be great if anyone could help me in chat session.

Comment: @yashikavaish Feel free to add me to a chat room, and ill try my best to help you out. :)

Comment: I am not getting the option , It would be grateful if You can add me in chat session , Thanks in advance @T.Nesset

Comment: @yashikavaish You should be invited

Comment: Was this a private or internal url?